# Why there is no debug info (DISubprogram) for extern function declaration?

Tags: c, clang, llvm, llvm-ir, dwarf

I have a header file like this:

```c
// test.h
#pragma once

void func(void);
```

and a source file calling the `func`:

```c
// test.c
void func_user() {
    func();
}
```

Then I compile these files in to LLVM IR using:

```sh
clang-13 -emit-llvm -O0 -g -S test.c -o test.ll
```

In `test.ll`, I got `DISubprogram` for `func_user` but not for `func`, why?

The full IR generated looks like:

```
; ModuleID = 'test.c'
source_filename = "test.c"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define dso_local void @func_user() #0 !dbg !9 {
  call void @func(), !dbg !12
  ret void, !dbg !13
}

declare dso_local void @func() #1

attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind optnone uwtable "frame-pointer"="all" "min-legal-vector-width"="0" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "tune-cpu"="generic" }
attributes #1 = { "frame-pointer"="all" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "tune-cpu"="generic" }

!llvm.dbg.cu = !{!0}
!llvm.module.flags = !{!3, !4, !5, !6, !7}
!llvm.ident = !{!8}

!0 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C99, file: !1, producer: "Ubuntu clang version 13.0.0-++20211007122600+fd1d8c2f04dd-1~exp1~20211006223358.115", isOptimized: false, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: FullDebug, enums: !2, splitDebugInlining: false, nameTableKind: None)
!1 = !DIFile(filename: "test.c", directory: "/home/richard/projects/linux-iso-analysis/demo")
!2 = !{}
!3 = !{i32 7, !"Dwarf Version", i32 4}
!4 = !{i32 2, !"Debug Info Version", i32 3}
!5 = !{i32 1, !"wchar_size", i32 4}
!6 = !{i32 7, !"uwtable", i32 1}
!7 = !{i32 7, !"frame-pointer", i32 2}
!8 = !{!"Ubuntu clang version 13.0.0-++20211007122600+fd1d8c2f04dd-1~exp1~20211006223358.115"}
!9 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "func_user", scope: !1, file: !1, line: 3, type: !10, scopeLine: 4, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition, unit: !0, retainedNodes: !2)
!10 = !DISubroutineType(types: !11)
!11 = !{null}
!12 = !DILocation(line: 5, column: 2, scope: !9)
!13 = !DILocation(line: 6, column: 1, scope: !9)
```

Comment: The DI* classes are debug information, such as source file and line number. If the function is extern, you don't know its source file or line number, and I can't think of any other debug info you do have. So why do you expect a DI*, what do you expect it to contain and why is its absence a problem?

Comment: Actually I encountered this problem when I try to build Linux kernel with LLVM, in that case some external functions had DI while some others didn’t. At first I thought maybe it’s because those functions’ names are started with underscore, but in fact not all of them are. So I couldn’t think of the reason why some have DI but others didn’t.

Comment: Back to this question, I expect there is a DISubprogram that describes the file and line of the function declaration.